# How does sshd under cygwin authenticate?

Tags: windows, ssh, cygwin, openssh

I know very little of Windows yet I have to work with a Windows server. The only way to make this bearable is with Cygwin and `sshd`. I have installed and configured `sshd`  but I don't really understand how it's doing authentication. And I also don't manage to log in, even though it's definitely running on port 22.

I have successfully used cygwin+ssh in the past (without much understanding of authentication). Both of those times I managed to get it working with local users. This time there's an entire LDAP-ish system as well (not sure what it's called in Windows).

There's an `/etc/passwd` file which is I generated with `mkpasswd`. Is there a simple way to add a user there that I can log in with?

There is talk about the `CYGWIN` environment variable, supposed to be set in `C:\cygwin\Cygwin.bat`, but I'm not sure how it affects things:

```
set CYGWIN=binmode tty ntsec
```

How does the OpenSSH server authenticate under Windows/Cygwin? How can I add one basic local user to use over SSH? How can I add one local user with administrator rights to use over SSH?

Answer (score 2):

`sshd` is using the same users as Windows.
The now optional `/etc/passwd` is used for storing the alternate cygwin name of the window user (same SSID) or to specify the `HOME` directory or the preferred shell.

The authentification method for the user is defined in its 
own `~/.ssh/config` file same as on other Unix systems. Use

```
/usr/bin/ssh-host-config
/usr/bin/ssh-user-config
```

to configure server and user.
Please note that all these settings are now obsolete.

```
set CYGWIN=binmode tty ntsec
```

Read https://cygwin.com/docs.html for updated info.

Comment: Do you mean that `set CYGWIN=binmode tty ntsec` is obsolete?
I don't think pointing to main page of the Cygwin docs is very useful in this case.

Comment: @matzeri is ntsec still required?

Comment: Can you help me with this? https://superuser.com/questions/1270014/a-specified-logon-session-does-not-exist-it-may-already-have-been-terminated-fo

Comment: yes matzeri is right all those options are obsolete as stated here: https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-cygwinenv.html